# How to disable WAC query string on a specific link, but not disable regular link tracking?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, email-template, email-tracking

Setting a variable with the complete A tag does make the WAC ignore the link, but it also gets ignored by the regular link tracking function. Is there a way to make a link be ignored by WAC, but not by link tracking? --> custom name="opencounter" type="tracking"

I want to track the clicks on the link, but not pass any parameters to the URL using WAC.

Comment: You would need to disable parameter manager to stop appending the WAC strings

Comment: I can’t verify it myself now, but what about adding IIF in WAC which checks linkname? Something like this: %%=IIF(INDEXOF(linkname,”nowac”) > 0,’’,[WAC Params go here]))=%%

Comment: EazyE, I don't want to disable the WAC altogether, just on a specific link. This would be on a link that the WAC parameters are causing the link to break or for some other reason. I want all the other links in the email to have the WAC tracking.